# Se produce un error de tipo System.AccessViolationException, SOLO cuando imprimo muchas etiquetas VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, impresión

Tengo un código para imprimir etiquetas en VB.NET (Visual Studio 2010), utilizando la clase PrintDocument, he generado una clase que contiene lo necesario para imprimir, mas el formato de la etiqueta que estoy generando. Cuando imprimo pocas etiquetas (unas 20) el código funciona sin problemas, pero cuando imprimo 100 o más etiquetas, el programa lanza un error, al ejecutar el programa en modo debug, observo que el error generado es el siguiente

> No se controló System.AccessViolationException
>   HResult=-2147467261
>    Message=Intento de leer o escribir en la memoria protegida. A menudo, esto indica que hay otra memoria dañada.
>    Source=System.Drawing

El error se produce en la función prt_PrintPage al querer asignar el valor de e.Graphics.DrawString.

Asumo que estoy reventando el buffer de la impresora, pero no sé como manejar ese error, o si es efectivamente eso el motivo del error, espero que alguien pueda darme luces por donde corregir esta falla, de antemano muchas gracias.

Mi clase para imprimir con PrintDocument es esta:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Imports System.Drawing.Text
Imports System.Threading.Thread
```

Public Class ImprimirPD

```
Private prtSettings As PrinterSettings
Private prtDoc As PrintDocument
Private prtFont As Font
Private barCodeFont As Font
Private CodeFont As Font
Private CompanyFont As Font
'
Private lineaActual As Integer

Private _datos As DataTable

Private _fileFontBarcode, _fileFontLabel As String

Public Sub New(ByVal fileFontBarcode As String, ByVal fileFontLabel As String)
    _fileFontBarcode = fileFontBarcode
    _fileFontLabel = fileFontLabel
    cargar_fuentes()
    ' La configuración actual de la impresora predeterminada
    prtSettings = New PrinterSettings
End Sub
```

## Region "Acciones"

```
Public Sub imprimir(ByVal datos As DataTable, ByVal selectAntes As Boolean, ByVal esPreview As Boolean)

    _datos = datos

    If prtSettings Is Nothing Then
        prtSettings = New PrinterSettings
        prtSettings.Collate = False
    End If
    '
    If selectAntes Then
        If seleccionarImpresora() = False Then Return
    End If
    '
    If prtDoc Is Nothing Then
        prtDoc = New PrintDocument
        AddHandler prtDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf prt_PrintPage
    End If
    '
    ' resetear la línea actual
    lineaActual = 0
    '
    'configuramos la hoja para imprimir
    Dim EPaperSize As New PaperSize("ETIQUETA", 410, 118)
    Dim EMargins As New Margins(100, 100, 100, 100)
    Dim EPrinterResolution As New PrinterResolution()
    EPrinterResolution.X = 203
    EPrinterResolution.Y = 203
    With prtSettings
        With .DefaultPageSettings
            .PaperSize = EPaperSize
            .Margins = EMargins
            .PrinterResolution = EPrinterResolution
            .Landscape = False
        End With
    End With

    ' la configuración a usar en la impresión
    prtDoc.PrinterSettings = prtSettings
    cargar_fuentes()

    If esPreview Then
        Dim prtPrev As New PrintPreviewDialog
        prtPrev.Document = prtDoc
        prtPrev.Text = "Previsualizar etiquetas"
        prtPrev.ShowDialog()
    Else
        prtDoc.Print()
    End If
End Sub

Public Function seleccionarImpresora() As Boolean
    Dim prtDialog As New PrintDialog
    If prtSettings Is Nothing Then
        prtSettings = New PrinterSettings
    End If

    With prtDialog
        .AllowPrintToFile = False
        .AllowSelection = False
        .AllowSomePages = False
        .PrintToFile = False
        .ShowHelp = False
        .ShowNetwork = True

        .PrinterSettings = prtSettings

        If .ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            prtSettings = .PrinterSettings
        Else
            Return False
        End If

    End With

    Return True
End Function
```

## End Region

## Region "Eventos"

```
Private Sub prt_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, _
                          ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)
    ' Este evento se produce cada vez que se va a imprimir una página
    Dim fontHeight As Single
    Dim yPos As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top
    Dim leftMargin As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
    Dim secBorder As Single
    Dim fila As DataRow
    fila = _datos.Rows(lineaActual)
    If fila(0) Then
        Dim strMascara, strOld, strDescrip, strLoteA As String
        Dim strFecha As Date
        strMascara = fila(1).ToString       'producto
        strOld = fila(2).ToString           'codigo_old
        strDescrip = fila(3).ToString       'descripcion
        strFecha = fila(4)                  'fecha_compra
        strLoteA = fila(9)                  'lote articulo
        leftMargin = 10
        secBorder = 80
        yPos = 10
        Dim Compañia, Dpart1, Dpart2, Dpart3 As String
        Dim largo As Integer = 50
        Compañia = "COMPAÑIA PRUEBA"
        If strDescrip.Length <= largo Then
            Dpart1 = strDescrip
            Dpart2 = ""
            Dpart3 = ""
        Else
            If strDescrip.Length <= largo * 2 Then
                Dpart1 = strDescrip.Substring(0, largo)
                Dpart2 = strDescrip.Substring(largo)
                Dpart3 = ""
            Else
                Dpart1 = strDescrip.Substring(0, largo)
                Dpart2 = strDescrip.Substring(largo, largo)
                Dpart3 = strDescrip.Substring(largo * 2)
            End If
        End If

        ' Asignar el tipo de letra
        fontHeight = 28 'CodeFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics) '27.76693


        ' imprimir cada una de las líneas de esta página
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Compañia, CompanyFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, yPos)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(strLoteA, CodeFont, Brushes.Black, 170, yPos)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(strMascara, CodeFont, Brushes.Black, 260, yPos)
        yPos += fontHeight

        fontHeight = 16 'prtFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics)  '15.61889

        'e.Graphics.DrawString("COD ANTIGUO : ", prtFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, yPos)
        'e.Graphics.DrawString(strOld, prtFont, Brushes.Black, secBorder, yPos)
        'yPos += fontHeight
        e.Graphics.DrawString("DESCRIPCION : ", prtFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, yPos)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Dpart1, prtFont, Brushes.Black, secBorder, yPos)
        yPos += fontHeight
        e.Graphics.DrawString("             ", prtFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, yPos)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Dpart2, prtFont, Brushes.Black, secBorder, yPos)
        yPos += fontHeight
        e.Graphics.DrawString("             ", prtFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, yPos)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Dpart3, prtFont, Brushes.Black, secBorder, yPos)
        yPos += fontHeight


        e.Graphics.DrawString("Fecha Compra : ", prtFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, yPos)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(strFecha.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), prtFont, Brushes.Black, secBorder, yPos)
        yPos += fontHeight
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Lote Artic. : ", prtFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, yPos)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(strLoteA, prtFont, Brushes.Black, secBorder, yPos)
        yPos += fontHeight

        e.Graphics.DrawString(FormatBarCode(strMascara), barCodeFont, Brushes.Black, 130, 85)

    End If
    lineaActual += 1
    If lineaActual < _datos.Rows.Count Then
        e.HasMorePages = True
    Else
        e.HasMorePages = False
    End If
End Sub
```

## End Region

## Region "Auxiliares"

`Private Function FormatBarCode(ByVal code As String) As String
    Dim barcode As String = String.Empty
    barcode = String.Format("*{0}*", code)
    Return barcode
End Function

Private Sub cargar_fuentes()
    ' La fuente a usar en los codigos de Barra
    Dim pfc As PrivateFontCollection = New PrivateFontCollection()
    pfc.AddFontFile(_fileFontBarcode)
    Dim fontCBar As FontFamily = pfc.Families(0)
    barCodeFont = New Font(fontCBar, 30, FontStyle.Regular)

    pfc = New PrivateFontCollection()
    pfc.AddFontFile(_fileFontLabel)
    Dim fontLabel As FontFamily = pfc.Families(0)
    ' La fuente a usar en la impresión
    prtFont = New Font(fontLabel, 9, FontStyle.Bold)
    CompanyFont = New Font(fontLabel, 14, FontStyle.Bold)
    CodeFont = New Font(fontLabel, 16, FontStyle.Bold)
End Sub`

## End Region

End Class

Comment: Prueba a depurar tu código, sobre todo en las líneas que empiezan con "e.Graphics", puede que alguno de los datos que estás usando en esas líneas no esté bien.

Comment: Pues al depurar, precisamente es donde se produce el error de AccessViolation, no creo que sea el dato específicamente, pues el error se presenta al imprimir más de 50 etiquetas, si se imprime solo 1, no genera error

Comment: Por depurar me refiero a la depuración o "debugging" de tu aplicación, por ejemplo por puntos de interrupción en líneas donde creas que se da el error, o pon dentro de un try/catch las líneas que te comenté, y un punto de interrupción en el catch, con eso puedes inspeccionar el valor de las variables en el momento en que se produce la excepción. Como desarrollador, nunca debes descartar que sean los datos. Otra cosa, ¿Liberas los recursos? Fuentes, pinceles, etc.

Comment: Revisaré como anda lo del try y catch, como lo indicas, sin embargo, puede que sea lo último que dices, que no libero recursos, pues no lo hago, como libero los recursos? tampoco tengo del todo claro que recursos estoy utilizando

Comment: Todos los fonts que utilizas, los brushes, etc. La mejor manera de liberar recursos es meterlos en un bloque using: using (var prtFont = new Font(...)) { /* aquí lo usas */ }  puedes tener using anidados, y declarar varias variables del mismo tipo en un mismo using.

Comment: Excelente Luis, ocupe declare las fonts dentro de using anidados en el evento prt_PrintPage (quite la funcion cargar_fuentes que tenia) y al hacer eso, imprimio como 300 etiquetas sin fallar, igualmente lo había colocado dentro de un bloque try catch como sugeriste, pero nunca se mostró el mensaje del catch, muchas gracias por tus comentarios.